# Chain AngularJS $timeout with Decreasing Interval

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to create an AngularJS application which gets an array of items then loops through that array (starting fast, then slowing down) until it lands on a final item. Its supposed to simulate spinning a wheel. However, AngularJS seems to be throwing an internal error when doing this.

> TypeError: undefined is not a function at  return logFn.apply(console, args);

Am I doing something wrong here or is there another way to create this behavior? The way I have it written now

```
var timeout = 250;
vm.locations = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E"];
vm.selectedLocation = "N/A";
vm.start = function () {
    getRandomLocation();
};

function getRandomLocation() {
    vm.selectedLocation = vm.locations[Math.floor(Math.random() * vm.locations.length)];
    timeout = timeout * 2;
    if (timeout < 5000) {
        $timeout(getRandomLocation(), timeout);
    } else {
        log(vm.selectedLocation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is in your `log` call - show us where and how you define `log` or swap it into `console.log` - also you should be passing getRandomLocation into `$timeout` instead of calling it, also this could be a `for` loop with promises.

Comment: The solution was to pass getRandomLocation into `$timeout`. It should've simply been `$timeout(getRandomLocation, timeout);`

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, but the error you got is not because of that.